# Java HTTP Error 404 - Jetty

Tags: java, xml, maven, servlets

Hi I'm following a college tutorial using jetty in java. I can't get it to run, despite following the tutorial.

Error
[image]

The below is my code
    package com.mycompany.jerseytutorial;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class Tester {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response sayHelloWorld(@PathParam("param") String message) {
    String output = "Hello " + message + "!";
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
}
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>JerseyTutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>JerseyTutorial</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.4.v20141103</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>


                </httpConnector>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                <!-- defaultsDescriptor>
                ,→ src/test/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml
                ,→ </defaultsDescriptor-->
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WEB.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.jerseyexample</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with it. I'm typing in the right URL path. I solved a 503 error, then i got this 404 error afterwards, so i'm pretty stumped at the moment.

Comment: Can you post the complete URL that you type?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/hello/jack

Comment: Change the url to localhost:8080/JerseyTutorial/api/hello/jack and check.

Comment: Exact same error. That's really weird. I followed my lecturers tutorial video step by step. I set up my localhost by ticking add ons in windows. Is that ok?

Comment: Check your package as suggested by Bedla below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey is scanning package `com.mycompany.jerseyexample` and your restlet is implemented in package `com.mycompany.jerseytutorial`. So you can move your class, or edit `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` param.